# ! is required but not allowed for custom command

Tags: sessions

I'm using Neovim 0.3.7. I have a default session file that loads up a number of files I'm working on at the moment. To save and load the sessions I have the following custom commands defined:

```
let sessionlocation = maindir.'/basetest.vim'
exe 'command Sdfs mks' sessionlocation
exe 'command Ldfs source' sessionlocation
```

This worked fine when I first saved the session. But now I have closed some tabs and opened some new ones and I want the *current* file layout to be the default session. When I try to run `:Sdfs` I get the error message:

```
E189 "..." exists (add ! to overwrite)
```

where `...` is the session file directory. That makes sense. But when I run `:Sdfs!` I get another error message:

```
E447: No ! allowed
```

**How can I allow `!` in my custom command so that I can overwrite my default session file?**

Comment: Note that I am running Windows 10. I have tested this behaviour with nvim opened as administrator and the behaviour persists.

Comment: `exe 'command! Sdfs mks' sessionlocation`
`exe 'command! Ldfs source' sessionlocation`

Comment: Thanks I tried the modification but unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`E189 "..." exists (add ! to overwrite)` is reported by [:h :mksession](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#%3Amksession) if session file exists , add `!` after `mks` should fix that:

```
exe 'command Sdfs mks!' sessionlocation
```

If you want to pass `!` from `Sdfs` to `mks`, use this:

```
exe 'command -bang Sdfs mks<bang>' sessionlocation
```

[:h :command-bang](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-bang)
[:h <bang>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Cbang%3E)

Comment: Thanks, the first one I really should have thought of, the second one is completely new to me and very interesting. I confirmed both work on my system and went with the latter solution in the end as it seems like good practice to have to explicitly overwrite.